# PHP static self:: / $this-> timings when querying a database

Tags: php, mysql, scope

I was doing a little database maintenance recently and was aiming to do a little error checking and safeguarding of certain things, I can list the tables and store them in an array without issue, however my problem arises when I try to verify the fields on that table... it does work- but on the second time of asking.
Have I missed something, or is this a timing issue inside of PHP?

**Simple table creation:**

```
CREATE TABLE `test_table` (
  `testfield1` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `testfield2` int(11) NULL,
  `testfield3` int(11) NULL,
  `testfield4` int(11) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`testfield1`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 COLLATE=latin1_general_ci;
```

**Stripped down PHP code:**

```
<?php
include_once("config.php");

class dbController {

    static $dbTables;
    static $curTable;
    static $dbTableFields;

    protected $dbh;

    function __construct() {
        // DB_SERVER, DB_NAME, DB_USER + DB_PASS login credentials 
        // defined in config.php.
        $this->dbh = new PDO(
            "mysql:host=". DB_SERVER .";dbname=" . DB_NAME,
            DB_USER,
            DB_PASS,
            array(PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => true)
        );

        // List the tables on the Database.
        $sth = $this->dbh->query("SHOW TABLES");
        $result = $sth->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        foreach($result as $table) {
            self::$dbTables[] = $table['Tables_in_' . DB_NAME];
        }
    }

    // Check field exists in table.
    function check_fields($table, $field) {

        if (in_array($table, self::$dbTables)) {
            if (self::$curTable != $table) {
                self::$curTable = $table;
                $sth = $this->dbh->query("SHOW COLUMNS FROM `$table`");
                $result = $sth->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
                foreach ($result as $field) {
                    self::$dbTableFields[] = $field['Field'];
                }
            }
            return in_array($field, self::$dbTableFields) 
                ? "true<br />" : "false<br />";
        }
    }
}
```

**Example**:

```
$db = new dbController();

// Calling the same command 3 times:

echo $db->check_fields('test_table','testfield1');
echo $db->check_fields('test_table','testfield1');
echo $db->check_fields('test_table','testfield1');
?>
```

**And the results:**

```
false
true
true
```

I tried replacing the static variable with a public one using $this-> to call and still get the same result. Am I missing something or is this a bug?

Comment: Check what's in `self::$dbTables` at the very end of the constructor.

Comment: <code>echo "<pre>";
print_r(dbController::$dbTables);
echo "</pre>";</code> yields an array of the tables on the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are overwriting your `$field` variable the first time you call the function:

```
function check_fields($table, $field) {
  ...
  foreach ($result as $field) {
                      ^^^^^^
```

At the end of that loop, `$field` contains an array with the last value instead of the string you expect it to be.

The second time you call the function with the same table name, that section is skipped as `self::$curTable === $table`.

Just change the name of the variable in the loop:

```
foreach ($result as $i) {
   self::$dbTableFields[] = $i['Field'];
}
```

Comment: and I _just_ went through the work of setting up this db and script on my localhost to begin debugging.  -.-

Comment: *grumbles* I knew it would be something really simple (or stupid) I'd missed, thanks! ;)

Comment: @Lucas You're welcome. If it works for you, please don't forget to mark the answer as accepted (the check-mark below the vote-count).

Comment: Sorry I'm quite new to this so it should be listed as answered now, even if I do feel a little silly for missing something so obvious- that said, were it to happen again I'll think to look at it this way in future!